# while iterating over vector<> get all other elements but ith

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Let's say we have a vector of size n.

The first element, we must get information from the other elements.

The second element, we must get information from the first and other elements.

The third element, we must get information from element one, two, and other elements.

etc.

How should I go about doing this?  Code so far..

```
vector<struct> myVector;
//vector filled..
for(Struct structure : myVector){
    //??
}
```

`vector[0]` needs `{vector[1] -> vector[n]}`

`vector[1]` needs `{vector[0] , vector[2] -> vector[n]}`

`vector[2]` needs `{vector[0] -> vector[1] , vector[3] -> vector[n]}`

etc.

My struct looks something like below and I need to get the degree information from each one in order to compare it to the current one (to see how far apart they are from one another).

```
struct Node {
    int degree;
    std::string name;
    int counter;
    Node(std::string aName, int aDegree, int nodeCounter) {
        degree = aDegree;
        name = aName;
        counter = nodeCounter;
    }
};
```

Comment: What kind of information you need from all other elements ? Could you show your "struct" and be little more specific ?

Comment: @P0W I added some more information and what i'm getting from the struct.

Comment: @Sounds like a Graph problem, the answers posted will do the job, but you might consider better alternative. Sorry, I'm not an algorithm Ninja

Comment: @P0W thanks for you input regardless!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple?

```
vector<int> data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

int ii = 0;    

for (int i : data)
{
    int jj = 0;
    for (int j : data)
    {
        if (ii == jj) continue;
        // do your stuff
        jj++            
    }
    ii++
}
```

If you need to operate on the initial vector before modifying it, if you need to modify it, then just make a copy first.

Comment: Ah, I had my head down so far that I wasn't even thinking about switching out to two for loops like that.  Thanks!

Comment: @hownowbrowncow: Yes, there's nothing in the two loops that depends on the vector contents (such code would belong in the `// do your stuff` part).

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
vector<int> data = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

auto current = data.cbegin();   
while (current != data.cend()) {
  for (auto it = data.cbegin(); it != data.cend(); ++it) {
    if (it != current)
      cout << *it;
  }

  cout << endl;
  ++current;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can test the ***addresses*** of the elements:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    std::string name;
    int degree;
    int counter;

    Node(std::string name, int degree, int counter)
    : name(name), degree(degree), counter(counter) // better to use init list
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Node> v {{"X", 1, 5}, {"O", 3, 2}, {"B", 8, 3}};

    for(auto& node1: v) // take references
    {
        for(auto& node2: v)
        {
            // compare addresses
            if(&node1 == &node2) // & = address of operator
                continue;

            // use node1 & node2 here
            std::cout << node1.name << ' ' << node2.name << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
X O
X B
O X
O B
B X
B O
```

Comment: *urge to buy beer intensifies*